# How do we reduce the size of an ADF mobile application?

Tags: android, mobile, android-emulator, oracle-adf

How do we reduce the size of an ADF mobile application?

My application contains the following:

1) two AMX pages
2) one managed Java bean

The size of the application when deployed to the Android emulator is 200MB.

Any pointers as to how this can be reduced will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Posted the same question here : https://forums.oracle.com/thread/2614050

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to package the application in Release mode - this will cut it down to about 10MB (which include the JVM). See instructions here: https://blogs.oracle.com/shay/entry/speed_up_adf_mobile_deployment

Comment: Thank you so much. will try the same and confirm.